# Systemd fluentd service outputs 127 error

Tags: centos, systemd

I have this systemd configuration file for fluentd

```
[Unit]
Description=Fluentd
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=xxx
Group=users
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/fluentd --config /etc/fluent/fluent.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

systemctl status outputs this:

```
xxx@test:/home/xxx # sudo systemctl status fluentd.service
● fluentd.service - Fluentd
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/fluentd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-02-08 20:51:05 UTC; 141ms ago
  Process: 5286 ExecStart=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/fluentd --config /etc/fluent/fluent.conf (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 5286 (code=exited, status=127)

Feb 08 20:51:05 xenoss.io systemd[1]: Unit fluentd.service entered failed state.
Feb 08 20:51:05 xenoss.io systemd[1]: fluentd.service failed.
Warning: fluentd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

But when I just run using this:

```
fluentd --config /etc/fluent/fluent.conf
```

I could successfully start it up, but with systemd it fails

Also which fluentd outputs:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/fluentd
```

Output of *sudo journalctl -xeu fluentd.service*:

```
-- The start-up result is done.
Feb 09 23:10:45 xxx systemd[1]: Starting Fluentd...
-- Subject: Unit fluentd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit fluentd.service has begun starting up.
Feb 09 23:10:45 xxx systemd[1]: fluentd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Feb 09 23:10:45 xxx systemd[1]: Unit fluentd.service entered failed state.
Feb 09 23:10:45 xxx systemd[1]: fluentd.service failed.
```

Comment: Run this `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and run again your service, if this one keeps failing then run (and add the output to your question) the command `sudo journalctl -xeu fluentd.service`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon Thank you for your reply, I added this additional information to the question

Comment: Is the full output of `sudo journalctl -xeu fluentd.service`? If it is, then it does not show relevant message for the error, But AFAIK `127` code represents a `command not found.`. I do not know what your `fluentd` does but you can try change the service `Type=simple` directive, maybe to `Type=forking` or `Type=oneshot`

Comment: Did you already run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`?